# Return first character SQL Derby

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, derby

I know that I can use something like

```
select distinct left(table.column, 1) as firstChar
from table
```

In MySQL to return just the first character of a field.
The problem is I'm working with SQL Derby :( and it does not like this syntax.

Is there a way to perform this query using derby?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [substr](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj93082.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substr(table.column,1,1) 
from table
order by table.column
```